# Что здесь означает «т.ц.»?

Tags: значение-слов, аббревиатуры

Описание ролика про клоны компьютерных игр:

> Клоны атакуют! По всем направлениям, нещадно, не сбавляя темпа. Неужели всё время было так? Похоже, что да, но то ли и дело пробьётся луч света в **т.ц.** Об избранных посланниках светила вам и поведают Вирджил и Димаус. Ах, да с наступающими праздниками! Увидимся в Новом Году!

Источник: [Атака Клонов - Современные Версии Аркадной Классики | youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFVNFEn_yxQ)

Answer (score 6):

Темное царство.
Классику знать надо.

[Луч света в тёмном царстве | ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%83%D1%87_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5)